# NullPointerException while using XSSFCell in Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I'm writing a program where I work with an excel file.
In this method, I want to iterate over the "I" column in excel (I've named it `COLUMN_MINUTE` and used .`convertColStringToIndex()` so I can work with the program easier) and find the first occurence of a number greater than the `int minute` parameter.
This, however is returning a Null pointer exception.

The XSFFSheet is initialised like this:

```
 File excelFile = new File ("C:\\Users\\vidon\\Desktop\\myFile.xlsx");
    FileInputStream inputStream = null;
    try {
        inputStream = new FileInputStream (excelFile);


        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
        XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheet(SHEET_NAME);
        int minuteEndsOnRow = 0;
        try {
            minuteEndsOnRow = getRowWithMinute (sheet, minute); //change here
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ExcelReader.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

                                 (....)

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        try {
            if (inputStream != null) {
                inputStream.close();
            }
        }
        catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

while the method itself looks like this.

```
public int getRowWithMinute (XSSFSheet sheet, int minute) throws Exception {
    int cellValue = -1;
    int row = 1; 
    XSSFCell cell;
    for (row=1; cellValue < minute; row++) {
         cell = sheet.getRow(row).getCell(CellReference.convertColStringToIndex(COLUMN_MINUTE));
        switch (cell.getCellTypeEnum()) {
            case NUMERIC:
                cellValue = (int) cell.getNumericCellValue();
                break;
            case STRING:
                String cv = (String) cell.getStringCellValue();
                cellValue = Integer.valueOf(cv);
                break;
            default:
                throw new Exception ("CellValue is not numeric or string.");
        }

    }

    return row;
}
```

What is causing the exception?

STACK TRACE:`

> INFO: Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:6, serverValue:20}] to 127.0.0.1:27017
>   Oct 21, 2017 3:15:56 AM utils.ExcelReader readExcel
>   SEVERE: null java.lang.NullPointerException   at
>   utils.ExcelReader.getRowWithMinute(ExcelReader.java:203)  at
>   utils.ExcelReader.readExcel(ExcelReader.java:76)  at
>   utils.StatisticsJSONBuilder.updateData(StatisticsJSONBuilder.java:199)
>     at JsonBuilderTest.main(JsonBuilderTest.java:46)

ExcelReader.java:203 is the row where I define

```
cell = sheet.getRow(row).getCell(CellReference.convertColStringToIndex(COLUMN_MINUTE));
```

Comment: A stacktrace would certainly be useful.

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm not as experienced and don't really know what a stacktrace is, nor do I know how to access it in Netbeans. Could you provide some info?

Comment: A stack trace is usually display in the console. So you should see your error in netbeans console and paste it in this post in order for us to help you. Without it we can’t see where the error happens

Comment: Would this be it:

Oct 21, 2017 3:15:56 AM utils.ExcelReader readExcel
SEVERE: null
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at utils.ExcelReader.getRowWithMinute(ExcelReader.java:203)
 at utils.ExcelReader.readExcel(ExcelReader.java:76)
 at utils.StatisticsJSONBuilder.updateData(StatisticsJSONBuilder.java:199)
 at JsonBuilderTest.main(JsonBuilderTest.java:46)

utils.ExcelReader.getRowWithMinute(ExcelReader.java:203) is the row where i define

cell = sheet.getRow(row).getCell(CellReference.convertColStringToIndex(COLUMN_MINUTE));

Comment: Are you sure your Row exists?